# How to print out package code?

Tags: perl

I have some difficulties with perl script which have one module (.pm) encoded by custom function and before module is loaded into .cgi scrcript is always decoded.

I could even let it be as it is but currently I have to do several changes in subroutines which this module contains and since it is encoded I am helpless ;/
So far I've tried several ways i.e:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use lib '.';
use ModuleX;   ### This is encoded module which I need
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
```

Unfortunatelly $body returns only ";" as a result ;/ I hope that it is possible to get those method code, but I have no idea what else I could do.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to deparse the `new` method in the `ModuleX` package? Then I believe that you want to say

```
my $body = $deparse->coderef2text(\&Modulex::new);
```